# Handling uncaught exceptions in C# console application

Tags: c#, .net, exception, mono, appdomain

I'm currently writing a server that hosts several modules. The server runs each module in a separate AppDomain. What I want to achieve is exception isolation, i.e. when one module throws an exception I don't want whole process to terminate, just this specific AppDomain. I know that I can tell CLR to fallback to old behaviour (.NET 1.0) when all uncaught exceptions in different threads were swallowed. However, this is not the most 'elegant' solution.

Answer (score 8):

How about subscribing to this event:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException
```

You'll have to cast the ExceptionObject property from type Object to Exception.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not exception handler, instead it only notifies you about unhandled exception. All in all application will still crash :(

Comment: when an unhandled exception happens, technically, the application has already crashed. This allows you to take an action and debug the application, or notify the user.